# How to connect locally installed Apache Hive to Azure datalake?

Tags: azure, hive, azure-data-lake

I have installed Apache Hive on my local system and I need to connect to Azure Data Lake to query the data from it. How to configure it?

Answer (score 0):

Details on how you can connect Hadoop to Azure Data Lake are available here - https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-azure-datalake/index.html.

You will need to have a recent version of Hadoop running in order to have the modules natively available.

There are blogs which talk about enabling this connectivity e.g. - https://medium.com/azure-data-lake/connecting-your-own-hadoop-or-spark-to-azure-data-lake-store-93d426d6a5f4.

But unless you are running Hadoop in an Azure Region where the Azure Data Lake Store (ADLS) account is located, your solution will be non-optimal. You will incur latency in data read/writes, as well as costs since you will be egressing data out of an Azure region during reads. Trust you have factored these into your planning.

Thanks,
Sachin Sheth,
Program Manager, Azure Data Lake.